# UILabel width changes depending Storyboard default View Device

Tags: swift, mask, layer

I have UILabel in storyboard and I set it horizontal spacing 0 with a UITextField. I set View device as: iPhone 4s. when I run my Xcode project by printing UILabel's width it prints 170 and when I change the View as Device: to some iPad, it prints 618. It should be an autoconstraint. I keep the UITextField's (2nd object) width fixed.

In Normal Conditions it works fine (tested it by giving background not printing, printing keeps the same above issue) but the width changes automatically when storyboard default device changes. But when we put a Masklayer, the issue starts.

Is it my Projects settings problem or something else?

My sample Project code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gREwY-o9dyvXnSAe2Ipz_Ew5NUSOUcdx

Comment: Can you please explain more? or add some images or code please

Comment: Show your constraint.

Comment: here is my sample Project:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gREwY-o9dyvXnSAe2Ipz_Ew5NUSOUcdx

Comment: What do you want? can you please explain?

Comment: @aBilal17 I want to keep the 2 elements with 0 horizontal spacing (after even setting the mask layer). and storyboard default device view is iPhone 4s. can u check it by running my Project?

Comment: yes let me check please